# Browser and AJAX response CORS headers differ

Tags: jquery, nginx, passenger, cors

I'm trying to setup a CORS enabled API that I can access via JavaScript.

The code I'm using to test is this:

```
$(function(){
get = function(url_fragment)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:        'my_api',
        dataType:   'json',
        cache:      false,
        success:    function(data)
        {
            alert('success');
        },
        error:      function(data)
        {
            alert('failure');
        }
    })
}
get('');
});
```

It's a fairly simple AJAX request.

I've enabled CORS in my nginx config

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

And when visiting the API in my browser, firebug shows the expected headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Connection          keep-alive
Content-Length      59
Content-Type        application/json;charset=utf-8
Server              nginx/1.0.11 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
Status              200
X-Frame-Options     sameorigin
X-Powered-By        Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
```

When I view the XHR request in firebug the CORS header isn't present:

```
Connection          keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type        text/plain
Server              nginx/1.0.11 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
Status              403
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Frame-Options     sameorigin
X-Powered-By        Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11
```

I do receieve the correct headers when using `curl`

```
$ curl -i my_api
HTTP/1.1            200 OK
Content-Type:       application/json;charset=utf-8
Connection:         keep-alive
Status:             200
X-Powered-By:       Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11
X-Frame-Options:    sameorigin
X-XSS-Protection:   1; mode=block
Content-Length:     61
Server:             nginx/1.0.11 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    *
```

Needless to say, I'm confused as to why this isn't working, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[add_header](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule#add_header) only works with a new status codes (200, 204, 301, 302 or 304).  The response missing the header is a 403, so add_header won't work.  The third party [headers more](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) module is more flexible, and can add headers for any status code.

Comment: Right, so that explains the difference in headers, however I was under the assumption that the reason it was returning 403 was because the origin location wasn't allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's returning the 403, but the X-Powered-By header makes me think it's coming from the ruby app.